# jqGrid register events on controls in edit mode with cell editing

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

On our project we were selecting the control in edit mode, to apply on change event like that:

```
var rowSelector = '#' + rowid + '_';
var controlSelector = rowSelector + columnName
var $(controlSelector).change(function () {
          //code here
    }
```

The problem is now, that with some of the bigger refactor (cell edit, using formatters etc.) ids of internal control are not in format rowid_columnName, but the sequential number is used instead of rowid. So, for example select element has `id="1_ColumnName"` instead of `"90433_ColumnName"` (90433 being the id of `tr`)
This actually brings up these questions:

1. How internal control should be selected correctly (through jqGrid API)?
2. What might be the cause(s) for making the jqGrid using sequential number instead of rowid?
3. Is this even the correct approach of registering change event for a dropdown? On what event it should be done with `cellEdit:true`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem typically exist if you fill the grid in a wrong way. It's important to understand that jqGrid **always** assign `id` attribute to every row of the grid (to `<tr>`). So you have to inform jqGrid where it should get the value in your input data. If you use array of items with named properties as input for jqGrid and the `id` have for example `_myId` value then you should use `jsonReader: {id: "_myId", repeatitems: false}`. Alternatively you can have another case where you have come column with the id value in `colModel`. In the case you can add `key: true` property to the definition of the column in `colModel`. In the case you don't need to use `jsonReader` with `id` property.

By the way I don't understand `change` code which you included. You don't need to use such kind of the code typically. `dataEvents` of [editoptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#editoptions) would be much better choice.

Comment: Thanks, Oleg. That gave me much of the required info how to continue with resolving curret problems. This change event is used because we do some specila logic regarding the selected value. I-m quite sure that's the wrong approach, so I'll check dataEvents.
What about question 1? Any preffered way getting an internal input of a tr in edit mode?

Comment: @theberserker: You are welcome! Do you have now `90433_ColumnName` as the `id`? Sorry, but I don't understand your question. What you mean under "internal control"? What problem you have currently? `How internal control should be selected correctly?` don't describe what you really need. You can define many [callbacks](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:cell_editing#events) so your callback function will be called and inform you or ask you about something during cell editing.

Comment: No, setting the id explicitly didn't work for me. Actually nothing changed there. Our Id column was marked as 'key: true' earlier, and that was it-working without any problem. Can't see anything braking in diffs of old and new code: [jqGenerator_new](https://www.dropbox.com/s/p1t0v2t84lxewq9/jqGenerator_new.html) [jqGenerator_old](https://www.dropbox.com/s/p7dewio6iyul75u/jqGenerator_old.html)

Comment: What I meant by _How internal control should be selected correctly?_ is actually how to get reference to the dropdown inside of a grid when it's edited. I know this is a wrong approach and I should be using `afterEditCell` but I was hoping I could avoid rewriting most of our grid customization (read: exploitation) :/ I just think it will be much less time consuming doing it the correct way

Comment: Sorry, but cell editing uses `iRow+"_"+nm` as the `id` of the editing cell (see [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.6.0/js/grid.celledit.js#L83)). The callback `afterEditCell` get `nm` and `iRow` as 2-nd and 4-d parameters (see [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.6.0/js/grid.celledit.js#L114)). So you can use `#` selector to make the binding which you need. I personally prefer inline editing instead of cell editing. In the case the id will be build in [the way](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.6.0/js/grid.inlinedit.js#L80): `id:rowid+"_"+nm`.

Comment: Thanks again, Oleg. Marked this as answer. We're actually making a change from cell to inline and we're too often relying on `id:rowid+"_"+nm`. This will be still a lots of fun...

Comment: @theberserker: You are welcome! I'g glad if I could help you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57513/discussion-between-the-berserker-and-oleg).

Comment: @Oleg please consider looking at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24861773/setrowdata-and-dirtycells