# SetRowData and DirtyCells

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I'm using SetRowData to set some row data in a jqGrid

```
jqColModel  = gJqGrid.jqGrid('getGridParam','colModel');
rowData = gJqGrid.jqGrid('getRowData', rowid);
for (var i=0; i<newData.length; i++){
    rowData[jqColModel[i+1].name] = newData[i];
}
gJqGrid.jqGrid('setRowData', rowid, rowData);
```

This is working as expected. The jqGrid row is being updated with the values from the `newData` object.

I'm then trying to get all the modified cells using

```
jqRows = gJqGrid.jqGrid('getChangedCells', 'dirty');
```

but this doesn't seem to be working. I'm trying to batch up all the changes and create a custom save event

My grid definition is as below

```
$(gJqSel_Table).jqGrid({
      caption     : 'jqGrid'
    , datatype    : 'local'
    , loadonce    : true 
    , data        : formattedLineData
    , colNames    : customColNames
    , colModel    : customColModel
    , autoencode  : true 
    , rowNum      : 1000 
    , keys        : true 
    , sortable    : false 
    , hidegrid    : false 
    , multiselect : false 
    , altRows     : false 
    , height      : '100%'
    , autowidth   : true 
    , shrinkToFit : true
    , cellEdit    : gSettings.editMode
    , cellsubmit  : 'clientArray'
    , afterEditCell : function (rowid) {
        var $editControl = $("#" + rowid).find("input, select, textarea");

        if ($editControl){
            $editControl.on('paste', function(e) {
                GridPaste(e, rowid);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Can someone provide some guidance about how I can

- use a JSON object to set all the cell values of a row
- flag each cell in the row as dirty so that the `getChangedCells` method knows that the values have changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more reading of the jqGrid documentation I found this

> ***setRowData***
>
> Do not use this method when you are editing the row or cell. This will
>   set the content and overwrite the input elements.
>
> http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods

Changing my code to use the `setCell` method works

- Cell value is updated
- Cell is marked as dirty and included in the `getChangedCells` results

My code is as below

```
jqColModel = gJqGrid.jqGrid('getGridParam','colModel');
for (var i=0; i<newData.length; i++){
    colName = jqColModel[i].name;
    gJqGrid.jqGrid('setCell', rowid, colName, newData[i], 'dirty-cell');
}
```

***Updated***

As @Oleg pointed out in the comments, I also had to add the following to mark the jqGrid *line* as edited:

```
gJqGrid.setRowData(rowid, false, 'edited');
```

Comment: one need add `"edited"` class to the rows (`<tr>` elements) additionally with adding `"dirty-cell"` to cells (`<td>` elements). You can use `getInd` (`gJqGrid.jqGrid("getInd",rowid,true)`) or  `$("#" + rowid)` to get the `<tr>` elements. See [the source code](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.6.0/js/grid.celledit.js#L466-L471) of `getChangedCells` method.

Comment: Thanks @Oleg I used `setRowData(rowid, false, 'edited')` to set the row class. This seems to work. Thanks for your comment